# Unable to build the android application with buildozer and kivy

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

This is my last hope of getting the fixed for the buildozer python issue. I already raised an issue in github for kivy. But there was no valid answer for it.

I'm not able to build the simple kivy android application using buildozer. I'm adding the log which I'm facing issue. Can anyone please help me with it.

Here are the versions I'm using

```
Windows: 10
Windows Subsystem for Linux: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Python: 3.8.10
```

Here is the error log for my issue

```
[INFO]:    Detected highest available build tools version to be 33.0.0-rc2
[DEBUG]:   -> running gradlew assembleDebug
[DEBUG]:        Unzipping /home/sunil/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.4.1-all/ihamk9lkfdnk0vct06i4nheil/gradle-6.4.1-all.zip to /home/sunil/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.4.1-all/ihamk9lkfdnk0vct06i4nheil
[DEBUG]:        Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
[DEBUG]:                at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1490)
[DEBUG]:                at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1385)
[DEBUG]:                at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1392)
[DEBUG]:                at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1197)
[DEBUG]:                at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1160)
[DEBUG]:                at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:718)
[DEBUG]:                at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:238)
[DEBUG]:                at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:168)
[DEBUG]:                at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:182)
[DEBUG]:                at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:157)
[DEBUG]:                at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:26)
[DEBUG]:                at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:67)
[DEBUG]:                at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:44)
[DEBUG]:                at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
[DEBUG]:                at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
[DEBUG]:                at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:126)
[DEBUG]:                at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
Exception in thread background thread for pid 133:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 1683, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 2662, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 2349, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/sunil/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 905, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

  RAN: /mnt/h/SwaraRaagamMob/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp/gradlew assembleDebug

  STDOUT:
Unzipping /home/sunil/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.4.1-all/ihamk9lkfdnk0vct06i4nheil/gradle-6.4.1-all.zip to /home/sunil/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.4.1-all/ihamk9lkfdnk0vct06i4nheil
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1490)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1385)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1392)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1197)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1160)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:718)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:238)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:168)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:182)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:157)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:26)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:67)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:126)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)


  STDERR:

WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Applying Java source code patches...
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
Warning: failed to apply patch (exit code 1), assuming it is already applied:  src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
[INFO]:    STDOUT:
        Unzipping /home/sunil/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.4.1-all/ihamk9lkfdnk0vct06i4nheil/gradle-6.4.1-all.zip to /home/sunil/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.4.1-all/ihamk9lkfdnk0vct06i4nheil
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1490)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1385)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1392)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1197)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1160)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:718)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:238)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:168)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:182)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:157)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:26)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:67)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:126)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
[INFO]:    STDERR:

[INFO]:    ENV:
export LESSOPEN='| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
export USER='sunil'
export SHLVL='1'
export HOME='/home/sunil'
export ANDROIDMINAPI='21'
export WSL_DISTRO_NAME='Ubuntu'
export LOGNAME='sunil'
export NAME='Sunil-Laptop'
export _='/home/sunil/.local/bin/buildozer'
export ANDROIDAPI='29'
export TERM='xterm-256color'
export ANDROIDNDK='/home/sunil/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
export PATH='/home/sunil/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/:/home/sunil/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/:/home/sunil/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c:/home/sunil/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools:/home/sunil/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/:/home/sunil/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/:/home/sunil/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c:/home/sunil/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools:/home/sunil/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/sunil/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft/jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Python39/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Python39/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Users/sunil/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.4/bin:/mnt/c/platform-tools:/snap/bin'
export LANG='C.UTF-8'
export ANDROIDSDK='/home/sunil/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
export LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
export SHELL='/bin/bash'
export PACKAGES_PATH='/home/sunil/.buildozer/android/packages'
export LESSCLOSE='/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
export PWD='/mnt/h/SwaraRaagamMob/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android'
export XDG_DATA_DIRS='/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
export HOSTTYPE='x86_64'
export WSLENV=''
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME='/home/sunil/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
export ANDROID_HOME='/home/sunil/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'

[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /mnt/h/SwaraRaagamMob/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp && /mnt/h/SwaraRaagamMob/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp/gradlew assembleDebug

[WARNING]: ERROR: /mnt/h/SwaraRaagamMob/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp/gradlew failed!
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --bootstrap sdl2 --dist_name myapp --name 'My Application' --version 0.1 --package org.test.myapp --minsdk 21 --ndk-api 21 --private /mnt/h/SwaraRaagamMob/.buildozer/android/app --android-entrypoint org.kivy.android.PythonActivity --android-apptheme @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch arm64-v8a --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir="/mnt/h/SwaraRaagamMob/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     WSL_DISTRO_NAME = 'Ubuntu'
#     NAME = 'Sunil-Laptop'
#     PWD = '/mnt/h/SwaraRaagamMob'
#     LOGNAME = 'sunil'
#     HOME = '/home/sunil'
#     LANG = 'C.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'sunil'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     WSLENV = ''
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = ('/home/sunil/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/sunil/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Microsoft/jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot/bin:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Python39/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Python39/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Users/sunil/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition '
 '2019.3.4/bin:/mnt/c/platform-tools:/snap/bin')
#     HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'
#     _ = '/home/sunil/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/sunil/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/sunil/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/sunil/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '29'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I tried everywhere and didn't find any solution for it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that you have to use the right android SDK version

Comment: I just followed the commands which were specified in the kivy documentation. Don't know if anything wrong with the kivy project itself.

Comment: write the android sdk version which you use in the spec file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @konstadinos, I tried with all the SDK versions 28, 29, 30. But that didn't changed the error

Comment: @TheHungryCub: That’s not the issue here. This answer doesn’t even include a link.

Answer (score 0):

```
Unzipping /home/sunil/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.4.1-all/ihamk9lkfdnk0vct06i4nheil/gradle-6.4.1-all.zip to /home/sunil/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.4.1-all/ihamk9lkfdnk0vct06i4nheil
[DEBUG]:        Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
```

Zip END header not found looks bad. Corrupted zip file?